# How to convert embedded JSON String inside JSON to java object?

Tags: java, json, jackson, jackson-databind

I have the below json, where the body key contains a value which is a string representation of a JSON object, how do I convert it to a Java Object ?

I can extract the body value by converting the JSON to a Map, but I don't know how I should proceed from there

```
input.json file

{
   "body": "{\n\t\"username\": \"TestUser\",\n\t\"password\": \"TestPassword\"\n}"
}
```

The User POJO is as below,

```
class User {
   private String username;
   private String password;

   ... getters, setters and no-arg constructor
}
```

My code looks something like this, I need to implement `convertToUser` function

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String jsonContent = readJsonFile("input.json");
    String escapedJsonBody = getBody(s);
    User user = convertToUser(escapedJsonBody, User.class);
}
```

I am already using jackson java library, any insights on doing this with jackson is highly appreciated.

Comment: try this once https://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-convert-java-object-to-from-json-jackson/

Comment: [Gson](https://github.com/google/gson) is an open‑source Java library to convert Java objects to JSON and back.

Comment: Both the above comments don't have anything helpful for the question, we need to get the object from a string embedded inside a JSON.

Comment: What is the output of `getBody()`?

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it is to create DTOs and converter. Having DTOs like (i have nested the class declarations jsut to save space in answer):

```
@Getter @Setter
public class Input { // this level maps to the whole input.json
    @JsonDeserialize(using =  BodyDeserializer.class) // custom deserializer below
    private Body body; // this is the body-attribute in JSON
    @Getter @Setter
    public static class Body {
        private User user;
        @Getter @Setter
        public static class User {
            private String username;
            private String password;
        }            
    }
}
```

the converter:

```
public class BodyDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<Body> {
    private ObjectMapper om = new ObjectMapper(); // this is to read the user from string
    @Override
    public Body deserialize(JsonParser p, DeserializationContext ctxt) throws IOException {
        String embedded = p.readValueAs(String.class);
        Body body = new Body();
        body.setUser(om.readValue(embedded, User.class)); // here is the trick
        return body;
    }
}
```

Use like:

```
ObjectMapper om = new ObjectMapper();
String input = "{\"body\": \"{\\n\\t\\\"username\\\": \\\"TestUser\\\",\\n\\t\\\"password\\\": \\\"TestPassword\\\"\\n}\"}";
Input r = om.readValue(input, Input.class);
```

This way the conversion happens in generic way only con might be that you do not like to create DTOs and dig the user like `Input.getBody().getUser();`

Comment: Got the below error,
`Exception in thread "main" com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException: Unrecognized field "username" (class eshop.common.lambdautil.Lambda$User), not marked as ignorable (0 known properties: ])
 at [Source: (String)"{
 "username": "TestUser",
 "password": "TestPassword"
}"; line: 2, column: 15] (through reference chain: eshop.common.lambdautil.LambdaTest$Input["body"]->eshop.common.lambdautil.Lambda$User["username"])
 at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException.from(UnrecognizedPropertyException.java:61)`

Comment: @vikkyhacks Do you get this when running exactly my code? If not, hard to tell what is wrong without seeing your deserializing code. This smells like you are trying to deserailize to wrong class that does not contain "username".

Comment: I tried this exact code, what is happening is, the whole body value is treated as one giant string. Its trying to find a constructor matching the string `{ "username": "TestUser", "password": "TestPassword" }`

Comment: @vikkyhacks Weird, working like a charm with me. Anyway I had the deserializer annotation in a bit confusing position, moved it above field but not sure if it does matter, works me in both ways. I'm using jackson-databind, v 2.10.1.

Comment: Oh, let me try again

Comment: On Second now, can you please share your java file ?

Comment: @vikkyhacks I have to say i'm not really sure what you are after. But I realized that maybe you are trying to deserializer to a wrong User.class so check what you are importing in the converter (eshop.common.lambdautil.Lambda$User) code, it should be the User in the Input class.